# Not able to install SNMP on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, snmp, mariadb

I am trying to install SNMP utility on my CentOS. I have Mysql pre-installed on the machine. I am getting following error :

```
yum install net-snmp
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
 * extras: ftp.hosteurope.de
 * updates: centos.mirror.iweb.ca
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package net-snmp.x86_64 1:5.7.2-24.el7_3.2 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7_3.2.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.52-1.el7 will be installed
Removing mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.52-1.el7 - u due to obsoletes from installed mysql-community-libs-5.7.16-1.el7.x86_64
--> Restarting Dependency Resolution with new changes.
--> Running transaction check
---> Package mariadb-libs.x86_64 1:5.5.52-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit) for package: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7_3.2.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:net-snmp-5.7.2-24.el7_3.2.x86_64 (updates)
           Requires: libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
           Available: 1:mariadb-libs-5.5.52-1.el7.x86_64 (base)
               libmysqlclient.so.18()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Can somebody give an idea how to resolve this?

Comment: I think it's trying to install some dependency from mariadb but since mysql is pre-installed, it's not able to proceed.

Comment: Try to update `mariadb-libs` and then run the installation again

Answer (score 0):

I think mysql-community packages isn't used in the system, so removed the `mysql-community*` packages and `net-snmp` installed all fine.

```
rpm -e  mysql-community-client mysql-community-libs mysql-community-common mysql-community-server
```